# JAX-RS AsyncResponse.resume() with Location header

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, jax-rs, resteasy

***UPDATE***

Some more digging showed that thrown Exceptions were dropped and the actual problem is that an injected `UriInfo` could not be resolved in the AsyncResponse's thread!

Accessing `@Context UriInfo uriInfo;` during `AsyncResponse.resume()` gives the following `LoggableFailure`'s message:

> Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo

***ORIGINAL***

According to [RFC 7231 HTTP/1.1 Semantics and Control](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3), a `POST`should return `201 CREATED` and supply the new resource's location in the header:

> the origin server
> SHOULD send a 201 (Created) response containing a Location header
> field that provides an identifier for the primary resource created
> (Section 7.1.2) and a representation that describes the status of the
> request while referring to the new resource(s).

When writing a synchronous REST Server, the `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`offers the `Response.created()` shorthand which does exactly that.

I would save the new entity, build an `URI` and return

```
return Response.created(createURL(created)).build();
```

However, when I switch to an asynchronous approach utilizing a

`@Suspended javax.ws.rs.container.AsyncResponse`

the HTTP request on the client will hang infinitely:

```
@POST
public void createUser(@Valid User user, @Suspended AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
    executorService.submit(() -> {
        User created = userService.create(user);
        asyncResponse.resume(
                Response.created(createURL(created)).build()
        );
    });
}
```

Through trial-and-error I found out that the modified location header is responsible.
If I return my entity and set the `201 Created`, without touching the header, the request will eventually resolve:

```
@POST
public void createUser(@Valid User user, @Suspended AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
    executorService.submit(() -> {
        User created = userService.create(user);
        asyncResponse.resume(
                Response.status(Status.CREATED).entity(created).build()  //this works
                //Response.created(createURL(created)).build()
        );
    });
}
```

**So what's the problem? Am I misunderstanding the concepts?**

I am running RestEasy on GlassFish4.1
If you need more information, please comment!

***edit***

As soon as I change any link or the header, the request will hang.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***In case anyone ever has the same problem:***

The problem was that I created the location header through an injected `@Context UriInfo uriInfo` using its `.getAbsolutePathBuilder()`.

The approach was working in a synchronous server because the thread which accessed the UriInfo still had the same Request context.

However, when I switched to an async approach, the underlying `Runnable` which eventually had to access `uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder()` was NOT within any context - thus throwing an exception which halted further execution.

***The workaround:***

In any async method which should return a location header, I `.getAbsolutePathBuilder()` while still within the context. The `UriBuilder` implemantion can then be used within the async run:

```
@POST
public void createUser(@Valid User user, @Suspended AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
    UriBuilder ub = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder();

    executorService.submit(() -> {
        User created = userService.create(user);
        asyncResponse.resume(
                Response.created(createURL(ub, created)).build()
        );
    });
}

private URI createURL(UriBuilder builder, ApiRepresentation entity) {
    return builder.path(entity.getId().toString()).build();
}
```